# Android Studio: setOnDateChangeListener not working

Tags: java, android

I have looked through many websites, and even youtube videos and none of them work. i keep getting the same error. Everything works until i start using the setOnDateChangeListener command. it is honestly very stressfull.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CalendarView calendarView;
    TextView myDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        myDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myDate);


        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                String date = (month + 1) + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year;
                myDate.setText(date);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And these are the errors i get

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.calendarhke, PID: 10946
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calendarhke/com.example.calendarhke.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(android.widget.CalendarView$OnDateChangeListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3333)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2043)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7464)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(android.widget.CalendarView$OnDateChangeListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.calendarhke.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7990)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7979)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3308)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2043) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7464) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10946 SIG: 9
```

This is for a school project, please help me out

Comment: check xml. R.id.calendarView is not present probably there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Have you tried to use Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` which means that your calendar **is not initialized** thus getting the exception when trying to call a method on a null object.

Make sure that `R.id.calendarView` is indeed the correct id of the calendar view. Check again `activity_main.xml` for that id.

Comment: I found the ID, how would i change it?